# $\zeta(z)$ Identities and a Conjecture

Tags: calculus, number-theory, riemann-zeta

### Brief Introduction

I found something quite interesting and would like to share it here.

The surface area and volume of a unit radius $n$-sphere can be expressed in terms of the gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ as follows. Let's define the surface area
$$S(n) = \frac{2\sqrt{\pi^n}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}$$
and the volume
$$V(n) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi^n}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$$
Now let's define a function  $\theta_k(n)$ where $k$ is a 'dimensional shift' such that $S(n-k)$.

$\theta_k(n)$ can be expressed as a ratio as follows
$$\theta_k(n) = \frac{S(n-k)}{V(n)}$$
$$ = \frac{n\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi^k}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-k}{2}\right)}$$

---

There are many potentially interesting properties that $\theta_k(n)$ exhibits. Many identities like
$$\theta_0(n)=n$$
$$\theta_{2k}(n)\theta_{-2k}(n) = n(n-2k)\prod_{m=1}^{k-1}\frac{n-2m}{n+2m}$$
$$\theta_{-k}(n)= \pi^k \theta_{k}(n)$$
There is one that we will use for the next few parts and has many interesting relations, namely
$$\theta_{2n}(2n-1) = -\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}{\pi^n \sqrt{\pi}}$$
$\theta_k(n)$ in general appears in many different areas of mathematics

An example:
$$\sqrt{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n+2}e^{-x^2}\,dx=-\frac{\theta_{2n}(2n-1)}{2\left(-\pi\right)^n}$$

---

### Identities With The Riemann-Zeta Function

1. $$\frac{\zeta (\frac{1}{2}-n)}{\zeta(n+\frac{1}{2})} = -i^{n(n+1)}\frac{\theta_{2n}(2n-1)}{2^n}$$
2. $$\theta_{2n}(2n-1) = -\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2\pi)^n}$$
   which therefore implies
   $$\frac{\zeta (\frac{1}{2}-n)}{\zeta(n+\frac{1}{2})} = i^{n(n+1)}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(4\pi)^n}$$

---

Next I will present a conjecture based off of a single observation regarding the ratio of $\theta_k(n)$ and $\zeta(n)$.

### Conjecture

Let's start off with the following equation
$$\frac{2^{n}}{\theta_{2n}(2n-1)} = \phi(n) \zeta(n)$$

We are interested in finding the values of $\phi(n)$, namely for $\text{parity}(n) := \text{even}$ as these are rational.

(I managed to derive $\phi(2n) = (-1)^n\frac{2(4n)!!}{B_{2n}(4n-1)!!})$ however am unsure of whether this is correct or not for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

A few of the first values of $\phi(2n)$ (ignoring the $(-1)^n$ term)
$$\phi(0) = 2$$
$$\phi(2) = 32$$
$$\phi(4) = \frac{1536}{7}$$
$$\phi(6) = \frac{4096}{11}$$
and strangely
$$\theta_3(12) = \frac{1536}{7\pi^2}$$
This seems like quite a big coincidence.
The conjecture states that $$\theta_k(n) = \pi^{-\alpha}\phi(\beta)$$
for some $n, k$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}$

This conjecture being true would imply that any $\zeta(2n)$ can be expressed in terms of $\theta_k(n)$ (and $\pi$) alone, like demonstrated below

$$\frac{\theta_{8}(7)\theta_3(12)\pi^{2}}{2^{4}} = \frac{1}{\zeta(4)}$$

My question is simply: Is the conjecture true or not?

This is quite a big post and there are bound to be some mistakes here and there, so please correct any if you see some. The objective of this post is 1. to share a potentially interesting result, and 2. Ask whether the conjecture is true or not. If anyone has anything to contribute regarding the post, perhaps an application of $\theta_k(n)$ in a completely different field of mathematics, some identities with other well-known functions, etc then feel free to post it below. Thank you everybody for your patience

Edit: Thanks to Steven Clark for the corrections

(I have shortened the post by removing all of the lengthy proofs)

---

### Bounty (Expired)

Bounty for anyone who can prove (or disprove) this conjecture. Good luck!

Comment: See [Particular values of the Riemann zeta function - Even positive integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers).

Comment: Yes, that's where I derived $\phi(2n) = (-1)^{3n-1}\frac{2(4n)!!}{B_{2n}(4n-1)!!}\,\,\,\,\,\, (\text{for}\,\,\, m = n)$ from. To prove the conjecture one must prove it is of the form $\theta_k(n)$

Comment: Neither of your last two formulas for $\theta_{2n}(2n-1)$ seem to be correct. I seem to get $$\theta_{2 n}(2 n-1)=-\frac{1}{\pi ^n} \sqrt{\left|\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)}\right|}\tag{1}$$ and $$\theta_{2 n}(2 n-1)=-\frac{(2 n+1)\text{!!}}{(2 n+1) (2 \pi )^n}\tag{2}.$$

Comment: I believe one has $$\frac{\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)}{\zeta\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}=-i^{n (n+1)}\, 2^{-n}\, \theta_{2 n}(2 n-1)\tag{3}$$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Also I believe your formula for $\phi(2 n)$ (for $m=n$) should be $$\phi(2 n)=\frac{(-1)^{3 n}\, 2\, (4 n)\text{!!}}{B_{2 n}\, (4 n-1)\text{!!}}\tag{4}.$$

Comment: @StevenClark Thanks alot! This helps get rid of $\text{s}_n$

Comment: What happened to $m$ in your definition $\frac{2^{m}}{\theta_{2n}(2n-1)}=\phi(n)\, \zeta(n)$ for your conjecture $\theta_k(n)=\pi^{-\alpha}\, \phi(\beta)$? Are you assuming $m=\beta$ analogous to the assumption $m=n$ in your derived formula $\phi(2n)=(-1)^{3n}\, \frac{2\, (4n)!!}{B_{2n}\, (4n-1)!!}$?

Comment: @StevenClark I guess its best to assume $m = \beta$ indeed, but I kept it undefined on purpose as to keep the conjecture broad enough. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @StevenClark perhaps show your calculation's steps because I get the same $ \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\sqrt{(-1)^{2n}\left|\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}-n)}\right|}$ still

Comment: $(-1)^{2 n}=1$ so you don't need to include it. The square root has two solutions (positive and negative), and comparing evaluation of your derived formula for $\theta_{2n}(2n-1)$ in your question above to the evaluation of your definition of $\theta_k(n)$ the negative solution illustrated in formula (1) in my comment above is the correct solution. I'm not sure why you indicated $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}$ in your previous comment as the derived formula in your question above indicates $\frac{1}{\pi^n}$ similar to formula (1) in my comment above.

Comment: Formula (2) in my comment above is based on the observed difference in evaluations of your corresponding derived formula for $\theta_{2n}(2n-1)$ and your definition of $\theta_k(n)$, so it appears there's an error somewhere in your derivation.

Comment: @StevenClark I see now. Thanks for the corrections! I will edit the post removing the proofs for the identities which have been corrected as to shorten it and get straight to the point

Comment: Since $n$ is an integer then $(-1)^{3n}$ is just $(-1)^n$.

Comment: True, and I believe $\theta_{2 n}(2 n-1)$ can be simplified further as $$\theta_{2 n}(2 n-1)=-\frac{(2 n-1)\text{!!}}{(2 \pi )^n}\tag{5}.$$

Comment: @StevenClark Yes, I belive that was my original for with a typo (+ instead of -) and follows from (2n+1)!!/(2n+1)> Thank you for all your contributions thus far though

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627355/whats-the-intuitive-meaning-of-this-relation-between-volumes-of-n-balls-and-u

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly ,you want $\zeta(2n) = \frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma((n+k)/2)} 2^a \pi^b$

for integer $a,b,k$.

$\zeta(6) = \zeta(2*3) = \frac{\pi^6}{945} = \frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma((3+8)/2)} 2^4 \pi^6$

works where the gamma part is your " special function ".

It fails for $\zeta(2),\zeta(4)$ and many more.
In fact I think $\zeta(6)$ is the only case that works.

Notice that the bernouilli numbers are complicated and very different from factorials.
The bernouilli numbers have no closed form in terms of a ratio of gamma functions.
Notice we also need to check only a finite amount of $k$ values for each $\zeta(2n)$ since $n$ is fixed and too high or too low $k$ could never work.

Notice that for small $n$ we have $\zeta(2n) = 1/a_n \pi^{2n}$ , so unit fractions for the first cases. This makes a ratio of gamma's very unlikely.

So your conjecture is probably false.

Comment: Ah unfortunately there are many forms that $\theta_k(n)$ can take depending on $n$ and $k$, and the starting formula $\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma((n+k)/2)} 2^a \pi^b$ isn't correct. Notice that you can rewrite the conjecture to be strictly in terms of Riemann-zeta functions, and using identity 2. (if the conjecture is correct) would imply that the Bernoulli numbers can be expressed in terms of the Gamma function. Unfortunately I don't think your answer helps very much, but that could perhaps be due to my post being convoluted or hard to understand. If so let me know so i can fix it

Comment: @Mako $\zeta(2n)$ is expressed by Bernouilli numbers and powers of pi. So not easily by Gamma functions since Bernouilli has no simple closed forms. If you are asking if the Gamma function can be used as closed form for Bernouilli numbers than the answer is no. Also note that using the gamma functions  to compute rationals give a big growth rate to both denom and nom for large input usually ... So that does not seem like a good strategy.  
You changed and modified your question alot. If this answer and comment does not help you, please clarify exactly.

Comment: Is $$B_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}j^n,\quad n\ge0$$ not a closed form? The modifications made to my question were small errors, as well as deleting a large portion of unecessary proofs.
I appreciate the comment and answer but the starting point is wrong as it starts of asking whether $\zeta(2n) = \theta_k(m)$ for some integer inputs, which isn't what the conjecture asks. Does that make sense?

Comment: Does the edit to the post clarify things?

Comment: @Mako with closed sum I meant without sum symbol and gamma like. 
The edit changed nothing, so in your bounty question , you ask for product/ratios of ... well since those zeta(2n) are rationals times powers of pi , they are ratios of integers multiplied by integer powers of pi. So the questions makes no sense.

Comment: If it doesn't make sense- please suggest how I can improve it... 

If you say that it in itself doesn't make sense then consider this as an example:
$$\frac{\theta_{8}(7)\theta_3(12)\pi^{2}}{2^{4}} = \frac{1}{\zeta(4)}$$

Comment: ofcourse you can make almost all rationals with combining enough rational functions @Mako

Comment: Yes that's very true- I assume in this case it is just two $\theta_k(n)$ functions though , but I would have to prove that somehow

Comment: You are constantly changing your identities and questions and conjectures. You know how that feels ?

Comment: I'm have not changed any identities since Steven Clark's corrections, and the conjecture has always stayed the same, except the addition of the example for the conjecture so that it perhaps makes more sense. The only things changed are adding/removing titles and the formatting...?

Comment: If you look carefully at the edits, you see nothing really changes, except corrections, specificities, format, etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150296/discussion-between-mako-and-mick).